# SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized

Tags: python, syntax-error, comtypes

I am a beginner and have a problem after installing pycaw for the audio control using python, on putting the basic initialization code for pycaw, i get the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\volumeControl.py", line 7, in <module>
    from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 375
    except COMError, err:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

Basic initialization:-

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
```

I tried searching for this all over the web but could not find a fix
I also trying going into the module file inside the virtual env and parenthize by putting brackets around COMError, err
But same error with other lines in code came,
Also tried reinstalling pycaw and trying to install different versions of pycaw several times but nothing fixed

How to fix this error?

Comment: You appear to have a Python 2 version of `comtypes` installed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my python version installed is `Python 3.10.1`

Comment: You are running Python 3 with a *library* built for Python 2. What version of ˋcomtypesˋ are you using?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I'll try installing python 2

Comment: This is probably relevant: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/244

Comment: Python 2 is EOL. Don't use it anymore! Try to update the library. A virtual environment could be helpful.

Comment: On running `pip install comptypes --upgrade`, it says `Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in c:\users\...\env\lib\site-packages (1.1.10)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a time searching I found that comtypes uses a tool to be compatible with both python 2 and 3 and that is no longer works in new versions. I had to downgrade two packages and reinstall comtypes:

```
pip install setuptools==57.0.0 --force-reinstall
pip install wheel==0.36.2 --force-reinstall
pip uninstall comtypes
pip install --no-cache-dir comtypes
```

Answer (score 8):

I just figured out what the cryptic `"SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized"` message means.
All it's trying to tell you is that in the newer version of Python you're using, this syntax is no longer valid:

```
except COMError, err:
```

instead, you should be using this syntax:

```
except COMError(err):
```

Comment: This means something completely different: That the `except` handles instances *of instances* of `COMError`; unlikely to make sense unless some serious metaprogramming is involved. This will likely also fail outright because it passes `err` – which is usually undefined – as an argument to `COMError`.

Comment: @B K Yes, that was already understood, but you could not change every line of the package in your computer like that and also, even if you manage to some what do it, on reinstalling the package the error will occur again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that syntax does not work

Answer (score -2):

Try the syntax

```
except (OSError, e):
```

Comment: The error was in the module and there are many such lines in the module where this error came, so it would not be possible to change each and every line in the module itself.

Comment: You are right. Although the error is a simple edit, the real issue is backward compatibility of the support libraries. So not fixable without downgrading components.

Comment: Yes, You are right and that's what is done in @Romulo_Santos' answer

Comment: that syntax does not work

Answer (score -2):

You should some changes in the Python file.

For example, if you run the `sqlalchemy` library and here you got the error then you will edit the file of this directory.

- Locate the `exc.py` file. In your case, it seems to be in the directory: `~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\exc.py`.
- Open the `exc.py` file in a text editor.
- Find the line that contains the `except Exception, e: statement`.
- Replace that line with the following code: `except (Exception, e):

Comment: There are many such lines in that file, so it would not be possible to change each and every line in it. And also, like that if we would want to reinstall packages, we will have to do it again and again.

Comment: that syntax does not work