# How to connect to a vm using python (SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized)

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to connect to vm using python. I need to do a server healthcheck report

I have written the below code to connect to the vm but getting error

```
svr = "test8ap"
import winrm
import getpass
from pysphere.vi_server import VIServer
try:
    usrname = input("Enter Username: ")
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Enter Password: ')
except Exception as err:
   print('Error Occured : ', err)

def viConnect(vCenter,username,password,vmname):
    server = pysphere.VIServer()
    server.connect(vCenter,username,password)
    return getVm(server,vmname)

conn = viConnect('12.68.18.1',usrname,passwd,svr)
```

error

```
C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/VM_Data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\VM_Data.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pysphere.vi_server import VIServer
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pysphere\__init__.py", line 171, in <module>
    from pysphere.vi_task import VITask
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pysphere\vi_task.py", line 110
    except (VI.ZSI.FaultException), e:
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you please let me know what is the issue here.

Tried solution provided [SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized - comtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648404/syntaxerror-multiple-exception-types-must-be-parenthesized-comtypes)

but still getting same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized - comtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648404/syntaxerror-multiple-exception-types-must-be-parenthesized-comtypes)

Comment: Not an answer, but for what it's worth, I've developed quite a few internal tools that connected to remote virtual machines and opted to connect to them using SSH invoked through Python as a shell command. I installed SSH keys to avoid dealing with passwords. I wrote a wrapper class based on the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @RandomDavis: Tried the steps with comtypes, but still same error

Comment: So clearly some code you're running is for Python 2, that's the main problem I was trying to point out. Why do you think that is? Have you tried to make sure you're using a Python 3 version of the library that's throwing that error for you? Do you know if one exists?

Comment: @RandomDavis: I uninstalled and installed pysphere again. no changes. python interpreter also showing 3.10

Comment: `pysphere` was last updated almost 9 years ago, in 2013. Why do you expect such an old library to be compatible with the latest version of Python? The [PyPi page for it](https://pypi.org/project/pysphere/) only lists support for Python 2. The [official GitHub Page](https://github.com/argos83/pysphere) says "Since 2013 I'm NOT LONGER MAINTAINING this project." and "VMWare released its official [python bindings for vSphere](https://developercenter.vmware.com/-/vmware-vsphere-api-python-bindings) that you may want to check out."

Comment: So, yeah, maybe you're using a really old tutorial or something, but if you'd looked at any of the official pages of the repo, you'd clearly see why it's not working, and that it's a dead project. There's a [question](https://github.com/argos83/pysphere/issues/75) from *nearly 5 years ago* on the GitHub Issues Page asking when there will be Python 3 support. Someone provided a [link](https://github.com/machalekj/pysphere/tree/2to3) to their attempt at porting the project to Python 3, which you can try using, maybe. It sounds like the official VMWare Python bindings are the best option for you.

Comment: Ok. Also, if you really really want to use this ancient, dead, unmaintained and unsupported library for whatever reason, then it sounds like you would need to use Python 2 (which itself was deprecated over 2 years ago so I'd only use it as a last resort). Regardless, this is why it's so important to look up the documentation for the libraries you're using, and google for information about them, especially before posting here. All I did was a quick google search to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the code of the module you are using. Is that your module? If not try reinstalling it and checking weather it is compatible with your current python Version!

Comment: I uninstalled and installed pysphere again. no changes.

Comment: There is no bug, the library is just not compatible with Python 3